# Put a node submit form in a block

Tags: hooks

In Drupal 7, I have defined a block called `mycontenttype_block`. I would like the output of the block to be the node submit form for an existing content type, like this:

```
function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') 
{
    switch ($delta) 
    {
        case 'mycontenttype_block':
            $block['subject'] = t('Mycontenttype submission form');
            $block['content'] .= $something;
            return $block;
            break;
    }
}
```

Where `$something` is the form output. I tried setting `$something` to `drupal_get_form('mycontenttype_form)` but I can't get any output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in drupalsixlandia, I wanted to have this on a different page and did something along the lines of this to get it to work:

```
global $user;

module_load_include('inc','node','node.pages');
$type = 'TYPEOFNODE';
$node = array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => $user->name, 'type' => $type, 'language' => '');

return drupal_get_form($type .'_node_form', $node);
```

so perhaps D7 needs a similar `$node` argument as well.

ADDITION:  a quick look suggests D7 wants $node to be an object, not an array and does it by just doing:

```
$node = (object) array('uid' => $user->uid, ...
```

You might be able to grab its code directly and use it.  Looking back, I don't know why I just didn't grab this from `node.pages.inc` directly myself:

```
/**
 * Returns a node submission form.
 */
function node_add($type) {
  global $user;

  $types = node_type_get_types();
  $node = (object) array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''), 'type' => $type, 'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE);
  drupal_set_title(t('Create @name', array('@name' => $types[$type]->name)), PASS_THROUGH);
  $output = drupal_get_form($type . '_node_form', $node);

  return $output;
}
```

Ah...here's why.  I didn't like the title, and I doubt you want that if you are stuffing this in a block :)

Comment: Thanks, I had a Drupal 6 implementation similar to this but like you say it wasn't clear... this did the trick once I used the module_load_include() function! Thankyou.